# Magento 2 : How can I stop SQL attack through search bar

Tags: magento2, search, security, sql, core-hacks

It's a bot that is continuously attacking, I try to hide these special characters suggestion form dashboard also try to delete them but all in vain, it comes again the next day(Magneto 2.3.1).[image: search SQL special character]

Answer (score 0):

Hiding of `special character` is not a solution for your store bot attack.

You need to implement **web Firewall for your website**. You can use services like Cloudflare and Sucuri web firewall.

This hacking need to prevent at the network level. Not the application level.

I have faced the same type of issue, it is resolved by Web firewall.

Comment: is their any other way to stop them using code ?
and how cloud flare secure me through this ?

Comment: Hitting on code means server load and it does not resolve the issue. Not `Cloudflare`, i am talking about `Cloudflare Web firewall` .At webfirewall, you can block a user or a url and Block an ip and track user.

Comment: Also, the firewall has its logic  to auto block those users which has bot attacker pattern